# Print The Grand Total

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

Once user insert a quantity of a good and click on submit, this calculator should print the sub total of that good(quantity * unit price) and the grand total(sum of sub total rows).

please someone help me to write this jquery in JS fucntion..

```css
        body{
            font-family:Consolas;  
        } 

        table{
            border:1px solid blue; 
            padding-left:3px;
        }
        
        #submit{
            background-color:green;
            padding-left:20px           
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="font-size:30px;color:red;text-align:left;word-spacing:100px;">ABC Supermarket</h1>
    
    <table border-collapse="collapse" >
    
    
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th class="q">Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Bread</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="u1" value="120.00" readonly="readonly" onclick="reSum();"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q1" onclick="reSum();"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="s1" readonly="readonly"></td>            
        </tr>   

        

        <tr>
            <td>Grandtotal</td> 
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tot" readonly="readonly"></td>
        </tr>      
    
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="clear" id="clear"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" ></td>          
        </tr> 
      
    </table>
```

The JavaScript functions I wrote to replace the jqueries are below.

```
<script>
       function subTotal(u1,q1){
         var u1=document.getElementById("u1").value;
         var q1=document.getElementById("q1").value;
         var subTotal=u1*q1;
         var grandTotal= subTotal;
         document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML=subTotal;
         document.getElementById("tot").innerHTML=grandTotal;
       }
</script>



<script>
      
    function clear(){
    document.getElementById("q1").value="";
    document.getElementById("s1").value="";
    document.getElementById("tot").value="";
    }     

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working with your solution?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to "convert" jQuery to vanila, plain, javascript ?

Comment: Please clarify your issue. And provide link to codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: here I have put jqueries to submit button to calculate the sub total and the grand total. And also to the clear button to clear all the data. I want to replace this functions with java script functions without jqueries..

Comment: Codepen - https://codepen.io/Anna_L8/pen/XWaPZRW

Comment: You're going to need to make an attempt on your own in "translating" this. We can help when you get stuck. Research what each jQuery command does and then how to do it in plain Javascript.

Comment: I put the js function which I created. please show me the error and the place where I should change

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
   <td><input type="number" class="qty" value="" name="qty" id="qty" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;width: 100%;  padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;"></td>
     <td><input class="price" type="number" id="price" name="price"  style="border: 1px solid lightgray;width: 100%;  padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;" ></td>
    <td><input  class="total" type="number" name="total" id="total" style=";width: 100%; padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px; border:none ;font-size: 27px " ></td>
```

script

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.qty', function (){
        let Ele = $(this);
        let qtyEle = Ele.parent().parent().find('.price');
        let totalEle = Ele.parent().parent().find('.total');
        totalEle.val(qtyEle.val() * Ele.val());
    });
```